# How to groupBy and its count list of items into Map object in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-stream, lightweight-stream-api

I have a list of Booking and this Booking has field OfficeType as enum as follow

```
@Data
@Entity
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class)
public class Booking {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)")
    private String id;

   

    @Column(name = "office_type")
    private OfficeType officeType;
```

I get the list of Booking from db, and I need to return to client that list and grouped by *Office type* and *count* as:

```
List<Booking> bookingList = bookingRepository.findByStatus(Status.APPROVED);
        Map<OfficeType, Integer> officeTypeMap = new HashMap<>();
```

How can I stream that list into that map grouping by OfficeType and counts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lambda expression like below:

```
List<Booking> bookingList = bookingRepository.findByStatus(Status.APPROVED);
Map<OfficeType, Integer> officeTypeMap = bookingList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Booking::getOfficeType,Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: This is wrong, you are grouping by id, instead of OfficeType.

Comment: Sorry, that is a demo. I have edited just now.

Answer (score 3):

To generate a `Map` of type `Map<OfficeType,Integer>` you can either use *three-args* version of Collector `toMap()`, or a combination of Collectors `collectiongAndThen()` and `groupingBy()` + collector `counting()` as a downstream of grouping.

## toMap()

If you're not expecting a large amount of elements having the same `id`, you can use the following single-collector solution based on *three-args* [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)):

```
List<Booking> bookingList = bookingRepository.findByStatus(Status.APPROVED);
        
Map<OfficeType, Integer> officeTypeMap = bookingList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        OfficeType::getId,
        i -> 1,
        Integer::sum
    ));
```

**Note regarding performance:**

There can be a small overhead caused generating new instances of `Integer` (because code above operates with wrapper type and primitive `int`). But all instances of `Integer` having a value of less than `128` are cached by the JVM (i.e. they would be created only once, and then the same reference would be used). So if there's roughly a hundred of elements having identical `id` there would be **no** tangible difference between this single collector-solution and the one listed below.

## collectiongAndThen() & groupingBy()

This approach [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy(java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.stream.Collector)) in conjunction with [`counting()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting()) as a downstream might be more performant when number if the data is massive. In this case, accumulation through collector `counting()`, which calculates resulting value using primitive `long`, can more advantages.

To transform the `Long` into `Integer` we can wrap `groupingBy()` with [`collectingAndThen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.Function)).

```
List<Booking> bookingList = bookingRepository.findByStatus(Status.APPROVED);
        
Map<OfficeType, Integer> officeTypeMap = bookingList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(OfficeType::getId, Collectors.counting()),
        Long::intValue)
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be:

```java
bookingList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Booking::getOfficeType, Collectors.counting()));
```

For reference: [Collectors.counting()](https://stackabuse.com/guide-to-java-8-collectors-counting/)